# Reverse Triangle using shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, reverse

OK so Ive been at this for a couple days,im new to this whole bash UNIX system thing i just got into it but I am trying to write a script where the user inputs an integer and the script will take that integer and print out a triangle using the integer that was inputted as a base and decreasing until it reaches zero. An example would be:

```
reverse_triangle.bash 4
****
***
** 
*
```

so this is what I have so far but when I run it nothing happens I have no idea what is wrong

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1
count=1
for (( i=$input; i>=$count;i-- ))
       do 
           for (( j=1; j>=i; j++ ))
              do 
                   echo -n "*"
            done
       echo 
       done
exit 0
```

when I try to run it nothing happens it just goes to the next line. help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: sorry its supposed to say reverse_triangle.bash

Comment: Your test is wrong: it should be `j<=i` instead of `j>=i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment, your test is wrong: you need

```
for (( j=1; j<=i; j++ ))
```

instead of

```
for (( j=1; j>=i; j++ ))
```

Otherwise, this loop is only executed when `i=1`, and it becomes an infinite loop.

---

Now if you want another way to solve that, in a much better way:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $1 = +([[:digit:]]) ]] || { printf >&2 'Argument must be a number\n'; exit 1; }
number=$((10#$1))
for ((;number>=1;--number)); do
    printf -v spn '%*s' "$number"
    printf '%s\n' "${spn// /*}"
done
```

Why is it better? first off, we check that the argument is really a number. Without this, your code is subject to arbitrary code injection. Also, we make sure that the number is understood in radix 10 with `10#$1`. Otherwise, an argument like `09` would raise an error.

We don't really need an extra variable for the loop, the provided argument is good enough. Now the trick: to print *n* times a pattern, a cool method is to store *n* spaces in a variable with `printf`: `%*s` will expand to *n* spaces, where *n* is the corresponding argument found by `printf`.
For example:

```
printf '%s%*s%s\n' hello 42 world
```

would print:

```
hello                                     world
```

(with 42 spaces).

<sup>Editor's note: `%*s` will NOT generally expand to *n* spaces, as evidenced by above output, which contains *37* spaces.

Instead, the argument that `*` is mapped to,`42`, is the *field width* for the `s`field, which maps to the *following* argument,`world`, causing string `world` to be *left-space-padded to a length of 42*; since `world` has a character count of 5, *37* spaces are used for padding.

To make the example work as intended, use `printf '%s%*s%s\n' hello 42 '' world` - note the *empty string* argument following `42`, which *ensures that the entire field is made up of padding, i.e., spaces* (you'd get the same effect if *no* arguments followed `42`).</sup>

With `printf`'s `-v` option, we can store any string formatted by `printf` into a variable; here we're storing `$number` spaces in `spn`. Finally, we replace all spaces by the character `*`, using the expansion `${spn// /*}`.

---

Yet another possibility:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $1 = +([[:digit:]]) ]] || { printf >&2 'Argument must be a number\n'; exit 1; }
printf -v s '%*s' $((10#1))
s=${s// /*}
while [[ $s ]]; do
    printf '%s\n' "$s"
    s=${s%?}
done
```

This time we construct the variable `s` that contains a bunch of `*` (number given by user), using the previous technique. Then we have a `while` loop that loops while `s` is non empty. At each iteration we print the content of `s` and we remove a character with the expansion `${s%?}` that removes the last character of `s`.

Comment: Some great techniques in there. Two observations: (a) by using `[[ $1 = +([[:digit:]]) ]]`, i.e., an extended glob, you're relying on bash 4.1+; to also make it work on 3.2+, you could use regex matching: `[[ $1 =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]`. (cont'd below)

Answer (score 0):

Building on [gniourf_gniourf's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28615128/45375):

The following is simpler and performs significantly better:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

count=$1  # (... number-validation code omitted for brevity)

# Create the 1st line, composed of $count '*' chars, and store in var. $line.
printf -v line '%.s*' $(seq $count)

# Count from $count down to 1.
while (( count-- )); do
  # Print a *substring* of the 1st line based on the current value of $count.
  printf "%.${count}s\n" "$line"
done
```

- `printf -v line '*%.s' $(seq $count)` is a trick that prints `*` `$count` times, thanks to `%.s*` resulting in `*` for each argument supplied, irrespective of the arguments' values (thanks to `%.s`, which effectively ignores its argument). `$(seq $count)` expands to `$count` arguments, resulting in a string composed of `$count` `*` chars. overall, which - thanks to `-v line`, is stored in variable `$line`.
- `printf "%.${count}s\n" "$line"` prints a substring from the beginning of `$line` that is `$count` chars. long.